# PowerShell version of SPWebapplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled?

Tags: powershell, object-model, validation

Does some one know the PowerShell equivalent version of the following SharePoint object model code:

```
SPWebapplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost the same:

```
$Mywebapplication = Get-SPWebApplication $WebApplication.url
$Mywebapplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = $false
```